# Why is it acceptable to get NoClassDefFound errors in eclipse? What is the solution?

Tags: java, eclipse

$##@$%@

Why is it that it seems like when I do searching pertaining to the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CustomXmlBinding
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CustomXmlBinding
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Which is spit out from eclipse at me after trying to do a clean build, there is no fix? 
This is also accompanied by an informative popup window that says that no main class could be found, and the program will exit.  What happens to cause Eclipse to all of a sudden become corrupt? I am using helios, and it seems like this has occured for some time now. My project has one java file in it, CustomXmlBinding, which has a main method, and has run quite successfully for two days. Today, I did a project clean, tried to run again, and this is what starts happening. The best solution I see on the internet is "make a new workspace" and try again..is that acceptable?

Comment: Make a minimal example showing the issue.

Comment: public class Test{ public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("Hello"); } } this is literally all it takes sometimes. It's not going to happen every time. Something happens that causes the workspace to go corrupt or something.

Comment: -1: This is more of a rant than a question, and can not be reasonably answered in its current form since you don't provide enough information about your environment.

Comment: edit your original post and add the example there.  Not in a comment, which doesn't support formatting and is much harder to read.

Comment: Actually, I finally was able to figure out what seemed to be the problem in this case.

Comment: why the @#$@#$ downvote? upvoted sir, I had this exact same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally figured out what caused this for me - if there is a jar that you have added to your build path, but which has been deleted/renamed/whatever, eclipse loses track of that jar. Instead of complaining that it cant find the required lib or something, it throws this awefully terse message. Hope this helps some other people. I removed the jar from my build path and it worked again.

Also, thanks for the downvote. Perhaps if you will google "eclipse could not find the main class" you will see I am not the first or last who has had this problem.

Comment: You're welcome ;-) Seriously, considering that your question leaves the impression that the class not found was within the project you execute, but your answer shows that problem occured (among other things) because it was in a JAR added to the build path, it was pretty much impossible for anyone to give the right solution. And if the question cannot be answered, it is badly posed.

Comment: Eclipse will not be aware of changes made outside of Eclipse until you do a refresh.  This is a fundamental bit of Eclipse that trips up many people.

Comment: @meriton You misunderstood. The JAR in question is not where main was. main was found in my source file that was part of my workspace, not on my build path. @Jim Garrison eclipse was aware of the change - when I went to the build path configuration, it had already flagged the JAR as missing.

Comment: okay I am still not able to resolve this....I check my classpath and there's no sign of missing jar...it's all there. nothing has been touched. seriously....one will know how frustrating this is until you've experienced it...